# Suppress messages in R markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, ogr2ogr

In my Rmarkdown file, I would like to suppress the message that a GeoJSON file has been read.

I have tried including `{r message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}` but this does not work and also wrapping the function in `invisible()` - but still the same message appears in the html output:

```
invisible(polys <- readOGR("data.geojson", "OGRGeoJSON"))

## OGR data source with driver: GeoJSON 
## Source: "data.geojson", layer: "OGRGeoJSON"
## with 102 features
## It has 6 fields
```

Can anyone suggest a workaround?

Comment: Can you put the line in a chunk that is set to include = FALSE?

Comment: Have you tried using the `suppressMessages` function?

Comment: You could also try surrounding the command with `sink('/dev/null')` (to redirect output to `/dev/null`) and `sink()` (to return to normal).

Comment: The `include = FALSE` method works